# Delayed Auto-sign-in on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, auto-login

Gnome Display Manager has a timed sign-in capability so that if no user is chosen a default with auto-sign-in after some delay. Can this be done in Windows 7? If so then how?

I don't mind using a third party solution if it is free.

Comment: After some pretty intense looking around, I couldn't find anything free. [Nonfree](http://www.logonexpert.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can activate a automatic logon with this command:

```
control userpasswords2
```

(Just type it into command prompt or the Run dialog which can be opened with WIN + R)

1. Uncheck the setting "Users mus enter password....".
2. Click on `Apply`
3. Input Automatic Login Information

The timeout function is not possible, but you can press ALT (I'm not sure maybe it was STRG + SHIFT) before the user login starts. This will cancel the automatic login and you can login into another user account.

You can also press WIN + L to go quickly to the Logon Screen and login into your account.